# Android Espresso .inRoot(isDialog()) selecting wrong Root

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have several androidTest tests that use Espresso to test my app's UI.  I noticed that one started failing recently and the reason doesn't seem to make any sense.

The test launches an `AlertDialog` that takes a password in an `EditText`.  The start of the test looks like:

```
    // click the icon that launches the dialog
    onView(withId(R.id.action))
            .perform(click())

    onView(withText("Enter Password"))
            .inRoot(isDialog())
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))

    onView(withId(R.id.passwordInput))
            .inRoot(isDialog())
            .perform(typeText("test password"))

    onView(withText("Ok"))
            .inRoot(isDialog())
            .perform(click())

    ...
```

This test opens the dialog, finds the EditText, and types in the text.  It then fails trying to find the "Ok" button with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not be requesting layout for over 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Otherwise, something is seriously wrong. Selected Root:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c05d1c2, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c05d1c2, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81810100 wanim=0x103045b needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}}
. All Roots:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3827e0d, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3827e0d, has-window-focus=true, layout-params-type=2, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#20 ty=2 fl=#1800002 fmt=-3 wanim=0x103045c needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1026, height=468, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c05d1c2, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c05d1c2, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81810100 wanim=0x103045b needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}}
```

It looks like it's selecting the non-focused activity window instead of the focused dialog window (you can tell the difference based on their sizes).  This makes no sense as the first two `.inRoot` calls found the correct window just fine.

The documentation on root selection is pretty slim so I'm not sure why this isn't working, is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Espresso expert definitely, and I'm far from making a review of your code but I suspect that the *inRoot* invocation is overused in your code. As one can see in the *inRoot* method spec it is intended to 'change/make an interaction scoped to the root selected by the given root matcher'. You seem to use it to make sure that you still perform actions it your dialog context. So, maybe the final *preform* method invocation does not aim at the proper *View*. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: The problem is that without the `inRoot` calls, the elements aren't found.

Comment: Have you tried to analyse Hierarchy View at the Android Device Monitor?